# Filtering periods out of email addresses with regex

Tags: regex, email, filtering

I need to clean a set of gmail addresses that are functionally equivalent using a regex. You may know of the gmail hack where "brunette.thomas@gmail" is treated by gmail as "brunetteandrew@gmail".  People are entering multiple entries in a sweepstakes by adding periods to their email address.

I need to filter these down to just the alpha component of the email address, ie., turn:

> b.r.u.n.e.t.t.e.t.h.o.m.as@gmail.com

into:

> brunettethomas@gmail.com

regardless of the number of periods.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Regex doesn't modify strings, it just finds matches.  What language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to match all periods before the at-sign:

```
\.(?=.*@)
```

Then you can just globally replace it with null-string. This will only work on regexp dialects that support lookahead (you haven't stated which dialect you're using).