# Issue with Gmail contextual gadget email extractor

Tags: google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I've encountered a bug with the [`google.com:RecipientToEmailExtractor`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#supported_extractors) extractor. When receiving an email from an address looking like `a.b.cdef@gmail.com` (1 letter followed by 1 period), the extracted address I get is `abcdef@gmail.com`. The periods are removed. `ab.cd.ef@gmail.com` has no issues and extracts the correct address.

And the issue is only with the **To** address. **From** and **CC** extractors are ok.

Is there a way to correct this?

Also, since I couldn't find the proper channel to report this issue (no Google Group or issues page), where can I submit a bug report?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an issue of much concern. ab.cd.ef@gmail.com is equivalent to a.b.cdef@gmail.com and abcdef@gmail.com - the periods don't matter in the first part of the gmail.com address. See http://gmailblog.blogspot.ca/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html

Comment: I disagree on it not being an issue of much concern. At least in the context of the extractor (not how Gmail itself handles periods). It's inconsistent ("ab.cd.ef@gmail.com" is extracted with the periods), unpredictable (From and CC extract correctly) and undocumented. For example, the gadget I'm building searches an external list of contacts based on the extracted address. With the extractor, I can't find the matching contact with the email "a.b.cdef@gmail.com", since it queries for "abcdef@gmail.com".

Answer (score 0):

Google found me a link for GAS bugs: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Short-term you could write a function to always remove dots from addresses before comparing. Here's a suggestion from StackOverflow using regex: [Filtering periods out of email addresses with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595820/filtering-periods-out-of-email-addresses-with-regex) You might want to consider that "+" can be used, too. See [Looking for a regex to match a gmail plus address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205519/looking-for-a-regex-to-match-a-gmail-plus-address)

As for the proper channel, I recall (but can't find the info now) that the Google Group for GAS at one time specified that questions should be asked in Stack Overflow. I had posted a few GAS questions in Web Apps and asked them to be migrated here for that reason.